# Kali Linux not detecting wireless network in dual boot

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router

Am new to Linux. Just downloaded and installed Kali Linux 1.0.7 yesterday.

I have a wireless connection in the house.

But Kali doesn't seem to be detecting the network. I go to the network icon and see only wired connections there.

When I type ifconfig there appears to be an ethernet connection detected:

```
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 20:89:84e5:f0:37
              UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txquelen:1000
              RX bytes:0 (0.0B) TX bytes:0 (0.0B)
              Interrupt:16

lo          Link encap: local Loopback
             inet addr:127.0.1.1 Mask: 255.1.1.0
             inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
             UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
             RX packets:20 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
             TX packets:20 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
            collisions:0 txquelen:0
           RX bytes:1200(1.1 KiB) TX bytes:1200(1.1KiB)
```

But when I type

```
$ iwconfig

eth0: no wireless extensions

lo: no wireless extensions
```

How can I make it detect the connection? Please help. :(

---

EDIT 1:

```
$ lspci -nnk
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Atheros Communications Inc. Device [1969:10a0] (rev 01) Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3802] Kernel Driver in use : alx
02:00.0 Network controller [0280] :Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01) Subsystem:Lenovo Device [17aa:0611] Kernel Driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

Comment: Are you dual-booting with Windows 8/8.1 with fast start-up enabled?

Comment: Drivers might be missing for your card. Attach output of `sudo lshw -class network`

Comment: Dual Booting with Windows 7 64-bit. As for drivers I'll have to check and see

Comment: bash command not found :(

Is it lshw? that's the part not found

Comment: Ok, I guess `lshw` is not installed. Attach this `sudo lspci -nnk`

Comment: Actually for Kali Linux, even wicd manager is not installed. Is this normal?

Comment: Yeah, *wicd* is not installed by default. Default is Gnome's Network Manager. And attach output of `sudo lspci -nnk`

Comment: Very sorry but I'm not able to access the snapshot.

But I did check and it said that ethernet controller was some Atheron card and network controller was Broadcomm BCM43142

Comment: Here's the portion: 01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Atheros Communications Inc. Device [1969:10a0] (rev 01) Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3802] Kernel Driver in use : alx

Comment: Please update the original post with additional details and Don't post outputs in comments. And I'm interested in **Wireless LAN Controller**

Comment: 02:00.0 Network controller [0280] :Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01) Subsystem:Lenovo Device [17aa:0611] Kernel Driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge

Answer (score 2):

Your Wireless Card `BCM43142` is not supported by open source driver `b43` (See [this](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43?highlight=%28bcm43142%29))
Try installing their proprietary driver [Broadcom Linux STA](http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php)

Follow these steps to Build and install driver (Use root shell `sudo -i`):

1. Install required packages and tools

   ```
   # echo 'deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free' > /etc/apt/sources.list
   # echo 'deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free' > /etc/apt/sources.list
   # apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
   # apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
   # apt-get build-dep linux
   ```
2. Download proper Broadcom Linux STA driver from here (32-bit or 64-bit) http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php
3. Extract the tarball

   ```
   # mkdir hybrid_wl
   # cd hybrid_wl
   # tar xzf <path-to-tarball>/hybrid-v35*
   ```
4. Build Driver as Linux loadable Kernel Module

   ```
   # make clean
   # make
   ```
5. This will build `wl.ko` file. If this file is not present it means there were errors while building. Now you need to remove conflicting drivers. Check if any of confilicting drivers are present

   ```
   # lsmod  | grep "brcmsmac\|b43\|ssb\|bcma\|wl"
   ```
6. Remove those modules which are present already:

   ```
   # rmmod b43
   # rmmod brcmsmac
   # rmmod ssb
   # rmmod bcma
   # rmmod wl
   ```

   and Blacklist them to prevent loading them in future

   ```
   # echo "blacklist ssb" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
   # echo "blacklist bcma" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
   # echo "blacklist b43" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
   # echo "blacklist brcmsmac" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
   ```
7. Install the module

   ```
   # insmod lib80211
   # insmod wl.ko
   ```
8. Wait for few seconds for Network Manager to detect the new driver installation and check if Wifi is functional.

The instructions are taken from [here](http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/README.txt).

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: In the first step itself it's saying the packages are absent

Comment: add these lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.  

`deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free`
`deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try
`# apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi`
`# modprobe -r iwlwifi; modprobe iwlwifi`